# Configuring Spring Boot with Docker Compose: Selecting a Specific Database Service from Multiple Services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I'm currently facing a challenge with Docker Compose and Spring Boot Docker support. In my `compose.yaml` file, I've specified two database services, but my intention is to use only one of them, not both. The `compose.yaml` file is structured as follows:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  server:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    ---

  client:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    ---
```

The reason for having two services is that I plan to utilize the second service for another application. However, in the current setup, when dealing with a single database service, Spring Boot usually configures the [connection details](https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/19/spring-boot-31-connectiondetails-abstraction) automatically. With two services, I'm encountering difficulty in specifying which one to use. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
***************************

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method dataSource in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari required a single bean, but 2 were found:

    - jdbcConnectionDetailsForClient_database: defined in unknown location

    - jdbcConnectionDetailsForServer_database: defined in unknown location

This may be due to missing parameter name information

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

How can I configure my setup to use only one database service and not both? Please note that providing information for only one datasource is not resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by leveraging Docker's [profiles with Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) feature. `compose.yaml` file is updated as follows:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  server:
    profiles:
      - server
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    ---

  client:
    profiles:
      - client
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    ---
```

Additionally, in Spring Boot `application.properties` file, included the following property:

```
spring.docker.compose.profiles.active=server
```

With this configuration, only the services marked with the `server` profile in Docker compose file will be utilized by the Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run it on 2 different ports, Both can't be available on 3306 (default port)

Also you will need to define url, username and password for both one could be under spring.datasource (url, username, password) other could possibly be spring.customdb (url, username, password)

Create a @Configuration and add @Bean for DataSource bean for second database by reading application.yml/.properties file (spring.customdb params)

Primary datasource can be created by spring at the startup available in (spring.datasource)

Comment: @Afasr I have the database services running on two different ports to avoid conflicts when Docker is running. As I specified in my initial question, my goal is to utilize only one database service, not both. Consequently, I believe there's no need to configure datasource settings for both services. Additionally, I've highlighted in my answer that achieving this can be done using the Docker Compose profiles feature.

Comment: Ah, I see, You want to use either of the database at a time. Thanks, I misread your question.